# Why would the query optimiser show rows scanned = total number of matched rows despite filtering on an indexed column with a limit applied?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with the following structure:
[image]

The table has around 25000 rows.
Since I have an index on the column, `field1`, I see fewer scanned rows while running the `explain` query. My question, however, is after using `limit` (without an offset), why would it scan every matched row in the case of filtering with an indexed column instead of just the limit (in the examples below, which is 10)?

Here are the queries I ran and their corresponding results:

- Query 1: `explain SELECT id, field1 from exam_tests where field1 = 'val9' limit 10;`
- Result: [image]

---

- Query 2: `explain SELECT id, field1 from exam_tests where field2 = 'val9' limit 10;
- Result: [image]

---

- Query 3: `explain SELECT id, field1 from exam_tests where field2 = 'val9' order by field1 limit 10;`
- Result: [image]

---

- Query 4: `explain SELECT id, field1 from exam_tests where field1 = 'val9' order by field1 limit 10;`
- Result: [image]

---

Here are my questions:

1. On *Query1*, Even with an indexed column (on which the filtering happens) and a limit applied, why does the optimizer consider scanning every matched result? There are indeed 1287 rows with field1 = 'val9'. In addition, I also noticed that, if I try to filter field1 to a non-existent value, the explain returns rows=1! eg:
   `explain SELECT id, field1 from exam_tests where field1 = 'val11' order by field1 limit 10;` 
   Here, there's no row with value, `val11` for `field1`column. And in this case, I get the following result:
   [image]
2. On *Query3* Just because we add an order by indexed column, how would the query optimizer be able to get the required results without scanning the entire table (the filtered column,`field2`, doesn't have an index)?

Comment: Are you using `ENGINE=InnoDB`?

Comment: Yes, Engine is `InnoDB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rows` in `EXPLAIN`

- is an estimate, often a very crude estimate; and
- usually does not take into account `LIMIT`.

Query 1 -- The query was performed using just the index's BTree.  (clue:  "Using index").  It probably touched only 10 rows.  (No clue available in Explain)

Query 2 -- Full table scan (Clues: `All` and `Nulls`).  It read all the rows, but may have delivered only a fraction of the rows (Clue: Filter 10.00% -- again a crude estimate)

Query 3 -- Hmmm...  It picked the wrong [my opinion] way to perform the query; it decided to use the index without realizing that it might have to go through the entire table to find 10 rows.  `INDEX(field2, field1)`, *in this order* would be optimal.

Query 4 -- (Perhaps you typed it wrong?  The `ORDER BY` is unnecessary since the output has all rows with the same value.)

Other helpers:

- If you want to know exactly how many rows were touched, do this:

  ```
  FLUSH STATUS;
  SELECT ... ;
  SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
  ```
- `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`
- The "Optimizer trace".
- The slowlog records "rows examined".
- [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) (It includes the 'Handler' and Optimizer Trace tips.)

Perhaps the following addresses your final question.  If there are no matching rows in the table, there still has to be a probe to discover that fact.  That increases some *actual* row counts by 1, including 0 to 1.  Similarly, if ther are only 6 rows matching the `WHERE` (and less than the `LIMIT`), it will 'examine' 7 rows to realize it is time to stop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Rick James for a very detailed response; much appreciated!
After reading your answer, I set up slow query log and kept its time to 0 (so that I'll get the actual rows examined stats; also). The actual results seem to align with the understanding

Here are the results:
For Query1: 
`Query_time: 0.049632  Lock_time: 0.031625 Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 10`
---
For Query2:
`Query_time: 0.074131  Lock_time: 0.026171 Rows_sent: 2  Rows_examined: 24903`
----
For Query3:
`Query_time: 0.322848  Lock_time: 0.176126 Rows_sent: 2  Rows_examined: 24903`

Comment: For Query4 also, as expected, no additional rows were examined:
`Query_time: 0.083317  Lock_time: 0.055214 Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 10`

I did use `SQL_NO_CACHE` to avoid reusing cache.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify a few other points you had mentioned:
1. I ran query 4 to just make validate my understanding (about the usage of indexes was correct)
2. I understand the no matching case you mentioned. I decided to add that point since in that case, the optimizer seemed to show the correct (one) row count.